# What is the maximum mesh size for rabbit barrier?

Tags: fence, rabbits

I know the text book says 1" x 1".  But that sounds like a tidy, easy to remember plan, almost like a slogan.  Does anyone know if a rabbit can get thru 1" x 2" or 1.5" x 1.5", maybe even 2" x 2"?

Just to state: 3' high.  1' under the ground and / or 1' 'L' shape outward from rabbit-free area.  I'm not questioning that.  I'm only questioning the mesh size.

Please no opinions, scientific knowledge only.

Answer (score 2):

The mesh size needs to keep out four-inch-long baby rabbits that have just been weaned, as well as adults. A 2x2 inch mesh would be no problem for a baby to get through.

British Standard BS1722:2 specifies a maximum mesh size of 31mm and a minimum wire thickness of 18 gauge (1.1mm) since rabbits can bite through 19 gauge (1.0mm) wire.

Monthly inspections to block burrows dug under the fence and repair any other damage are recommended.

Full details here: http://adlib.everysite.co.uk/adlib/defra/content.aspx?id=000IL3890W.18WMARF372S91H